# BI Publisher administration access to a specificy model

Tags: bi-publisher

I was creating a data model and passed on the sql query and created parameters along with it, But due to some reason I am not able to see the output value as well when I run this query in toad I need to pass the administrator exec statement to see all the value so how do I insert administrator access to that value in BI publisher.

Comment: I have called the user id of the administrator in my BI publisher and it worked out. and my problem is solved.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have called the user id of the administrator in my BI publisher and it worked out. and my problem is solved.:)